# Feedback HangMan game using python and tkinter for GUI

Tags: python, tkinter, hangman

Having too much spare time during the quarantine I learned some basic python (plus tkinter for GUI) and made a little HangMan game :)
Would love any feedback for improvement.
Thank you.

```
import os
import random
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
from tkinter import messagebox
import pygame

# Window settings
root = Tk()
root.title("HangMan")
root.iconbitmap("images/icon.ico")
root.geometry("800x400")
root.resizable(width=False, height=False)


def disable_event():
    pass


root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", disable_event)  # Disable window "X" (close) button


pygame.mixer.init()
music_state = False


def play_music():
    global music_state

    if not music_state:
        pygame.mixer.music.load("music/The Witcher 3 OST.mp3")
        pygame.mixer.music.play(loops=0)
        music_state = True
    else:
        pygame.mixer.music.stop()
        music_state = False


def main_menu_():
    root.deiconify()

    global main_menu_bg

    global letter_change
    letter_change = 1
    global word_change
    word_change = 2

    # Create canvas and add background
    canvas = Canvas(root, width="800", height="450")
    canvas.pack()

    main_menu_bg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("images/main_bg.jpg").resize((800, 450), Image.ANTIALIAS))
    canvas.background = main_menu_bg
    canvas.create_image(0, 0, anchor=NW, image=main_menu_bg)

    # Add buttons to canvas
    start_btn = Button(root, text="New Game", width=15, command=new_game, borderwidth=5)
    canvas.create_window(400, 150, anchor=CENTER, window=start_btn)

    score_btn = Button(root, text="Score Board", width=15, command=score_board, borderwidth=5)
    canvas.create_window(400, 210, anchor=CENTER, window=score_btn)

    quit_btn = Button(root, text="Quit", width=15, command=quit_game, borderwidth=5)
    canvas.create_window(400, 270, anchor=CENTER, window=quit_btn)

    music_btn = Button(root, text="Music", command=play_music)
    canvas.create_window(770, 380, anchor=CENTER, window=music_btn)


def new_game():
    root.withdraw()  # Hide root window, to make it visible again use root.deiconify()

    global new_game_bg
    global new_game_window

    new_game_window = Toplevel()
    new_game_window.title("HangMan")
    new_game_window.iconbitmap("images/icon.ico")
    new_game_window.geometry("800x400")
    new_game_window.resizable(width=False, height=False)
    new_game_window.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", disable_event)  # Disable window "X" (close) button

    # Create canvas and add background
    canvas_new_game = Canvas(new_game_window, width="800", height="450")
    canvas_new_game.pack()

    new_game_bg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("images/main_bg.jpg").resize((800, 450), Image.ANTIALIAS))
    canvas_new_game.background = new_game_bg
    canvas_new_game.create_image(0, 0, anchor=NW, image=new_game_bg)

    instructions_lbl = Label(new_game_window, text="There are 4 different categories.\n"
                                                   "Choose as many as you'd like,"
                                                   "\nbut do choose wisely, this is not going to be easy!",
                             bg="#a5a0b6")
    canvas_new_game.create_window(400, 60, anchor=CENTER, window=instructions_lbl)

    # Will help knowing which categories were chosen
    var1 = StringVar(value="")
    var2 = StringVar(value="")
    var3 = StringVar(value="")
    var4 = StringVar(value="")

    anime_btn = Checkbutton(new_game_window, text="Anime", variable=var1, onvalue="a", offvalue="")
    canvas_new_game.create_window(340, 120, anchor=CENTER, window=anime_btn)
    games_btn = Checkbutton(new_game_window, text="Games", variable=var2, onvalue="g", offvalue="")
    canvas_new_game.create_window(440, 120, anchor=CENTER, window=games_btn)
    movies_btn = Checkbutton(new_game_window, text="Movies", variable=var3, onvalue="m", offvalue="")
    canvas_new_game.create_window(340, 170, anchor=CENTER, window=movies_btn)
    tv_btn = Checkbutton(new_game_window, text="TV-Shows", variable=var4, onvalue="t", offvalue="")
    canvas_new_game.create_window(440, 170, anchor=CENTER, window=tv_btn)

    start_new_game_btn = Button(new_game_window, text="Start new game", width=15,
                                command=lambda: [prepare(var1.get() + var2.get() + var3.get() + var4.get())]
                                , borderwidth=5)
    canvas_new_game.create_window(390, 220, anchor=CENTER, window=start_new_game_btn)

    back_menu_btn = Button(new_game_window, text="Main Menu", width=15, command=lambda: [main_menu_(),
                                                                                         new_game_window.destroy()]
                           , borderwidth=5)
    canvas_new_game.create_window(390, 260, anchor=CENTER, window=back_menu_btn)

    # quit_game_btn = Button(new_game_window, text="Quit game", width=15, command=quit_game)
    # canvas_new_game.create_window(390, 300, anchor=CENTER, window=quit_game_btn)

    music_btn = Button(new_game_window, text="Music", command=play_music)
    canvas_new_game.create_window(770, 380, anchor=CENTER, window=music_btn)


# choice variable will contain the user's wanted category for the game
def prepare(choice):
    global count_lines

    # Create file of words
    movies = open("movies list.txt", "r")  # Open word files
    games = open("games list.txt", "r")
    tv = open("tv list.txt", "r")
    anime = open("anime list.txt", "r")
    categories = ""
    file = open("temp.txt", "a+")  # File which will contain words from chosen categories
    if "a" or "g" or "m" or "t" in choice:
        if "m" in choice:
            categories += "Movies / "
            for i in movies.readlines():
                file.write(i)
        if "g" in choice:
            categories += "Games / "
            for j in games.readlines():
                file.write(j)
        if "t" in choice:
            categories += "TV-Shows / "
            for k in tv.readlines():
                file.write(k)
        if "a" in choice:
            categories += "Anime / "
            for t in anime.readlines():
                file.write(t)
        categories = categories[0:-3]  # Will go in label
    movies.close()  # Close word files
    anime.close()
    tv.close()
    games.close()
    file.close()

    # Get lines count
    categories_file = open("temp.txt", "r")
    count_lines = get_lines_count(categories_file)
    categories_file.close()

    # Get random word to guess
    random_num = random.randint(1, count_lines)  # Get a random integer
    word_to_guess = get_word(random_num)
    word_to_guess = word_to_guess[0:-1]  # Remove the "\n" char

    # Count word chars
    chars_count = get_chars_count(list(word_to_guess))

    # Create a variable same length as word to guess but made from _
    under_lines_guess = hide_word(word_to_guess)

    play(under_lines_guess, word_to_guess, chars_count)


def hide_word(word):
    hidden = ""
    for hide in range(len(word)):  # for 0 in (x-1)
        if word[hide] == " ":
            hidden += " "
        else:
            hidden += "_"
    return hidden


def get_chars_count(count_chars):
    counter_chars = 0
    for index in count_chars:
        if index != " ":
            counter_chars += 1
    return counter_chars


def get_lines_count(file):
    return sum(1 for line in file)  # For each line count 1+1+...


def get_word(random_number):
    global count_lines

    f = open("temp.txt", "r")
    lines = f.readlines()
    ret = lines[random_number - 1]
    f.close()
    f_new = open("temp.txt", "w")
    for line in lines:  # Write all lines to the file except the one with the word used
        if line != lines[random_number - 1]:
            f_new.write(line)
    f_new.close()

    count_lines -= 1  # Since one line is gone (used and deleted)

    return ret


def close_window():
    option_window.destroy()


def option_a():
    global count_lines
    global word_change
    global letter_change

    if word_change <= 0:
        messagebox.showwarning("Used it all", "You used all of your word change options!")
        option_window.destroy()
        return

    # Get random word to guess
    random_num = random.randint(1, count_lines)  # Get a random integer
    word_to_guess = get_word(random_num)
    word_to_guess = word_to_guess[0:-1]  # Remove the "\n" char

    # Count word chars
    chars_count = get_chars_count(list(word_to_guess))

    # Create a variable same length as word to guess but made from _
    under_lines_guess = hide_word(word_to_guess)
    word_change -= 1

    play_window.destroy()
    option_window.destroy()

    play(under_lines_guess, word_to_guess, chars_count)


def option_b():
    global chars_bank
    global counter
    global letter_change

    if letter_change <= 0:
        messagebox.showwarning("Used it all", "You used all of your letter helper options!")
        option_window.destroy()
        return

    answer_b = list(wordd)  # When done, do - "".join(list to join as string)
    upper_word = wordd.upper()
    upper_word_list_b = list(upper_word)

    len_wordd = len(wordd) - 1
    used_check = True
    while used_check:
        random_num = random.randint(0, len_wordd)
        char_reveal = wordd[random_num-1]

        if char_reveal not in chars_bank:
            chars_bank += char_reveal
            while char_reveal.upper() in str(answer_b).upper():
                print(char_reveal.upper() + str(answer_b).upper())
                i = upper_word_list_b.index(char_reveal.upper())  # Change input char and it's duplicates
                under_lines[i] = answer_b[i]
                answer_b[i] = " "
                upper_word_list_b[i] = " "
                counter -= 1
            if counter == 0:
                messagebox.showinfo("WINNER", "You win!!!")
                answer_ = messagebox.askyesno("HangMan", "Would you like to play again?")
                if answer_ == 0:
                    quit_game()
                else:
                    if os.path.isfile("temp.txt"):  # In case the file was created
                        os.remove("temp.txt")  # Delete file (no longer needed)
                    new_game_window.destroy()
                    play_window.destroy()
                    option_window.destroy()
                    root.deiconify()
            used_check = False

    letter_change -= 1

    list_chars_bank_ = list(chars_bank)
    bank_lbl = Label(play_window, text="Used characters bank:\n" + " ".join(list_chars_bank_).upper())
    canvas_play.create_window(70, 270, anchor=CENTER, window=bank_lbl)

    underlines_lbl = Label(play_window, text=" ".join(under_lines))
    canvas_play.create_window(400, 310, anchor=CENTER, window=underlines_lbl)

    guesses_lbl = Label(play_window, text="You have " + str(guesses) + " guesses left")
    canvas_play.create_window(400, 340, anchor=CENTER, window=guesses_lbl)

    option_window.destroy()


def assistance():
    global word_change
    global letter_change

    global option_window

    if word_change == 0 and letter_change == 0:
        messagebox.showinfo("Assistance menu", "You don't have any more assistance options to use.")
    else:
        option_window = Toplevel()
        option_window.title("Assistance menu")
        option_window.iconbitmap("images/icon.ico")
        option_window.geometry("270x219")
        option_window.resizable(width=False, height=False)
        option_window.attributes("-topmost", "true")

        # Create canvas and add background
        canvas_option = Canvas(option_window, width="270", height="219")
        canvas_option.pack()

        option_bg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("images/choosewisely.jpg").resize((270, 219), Image.ANTIALIAS))
        canvas_option.background = option_bg
        canvas_option.create_image(0, 0, anchor=NW, image=option_bg)

        option_text = ("Choose an option:\nA) Change word (uses left: " + str(word_change)
                       + ")\nB) Letter helper (uses left: " + str(letter_change) + ")")

        option_lbl = Label(option_window, text=option_text)
        canvas_option.create_window(135, 55, anchor=CENTER, window=option_lbl)

        option_a_btn = Button(option_window, text="Option A", borderwidth=5, command=option_a)
        canvas_option.create_window(85, 150, anchor=CENTER, window=option_a_btn)

        option_b_btn = Button(option_window, text="Option B", borderwidth=5, command=option_b)
        canvas_option.create_window(185, 150, anchor=CENTER, window=option_b_btn)

        cancel_btn = Button(option_window, text="Nah... I don't need any help", borderwidth=5,
                            command=close_window)
        canvas_option.create_window(135, 195, anchor=CENTER, window=cancel_btn)


def my_answer():
    global chars_bank

    global wordd

    global counter

    global guesses

    global list_chars_bank

    global under_lines

    if e.get()[0:1] in "\n =+-*/.`~!@#$%^&*()_,';:":
        messagebox.showwarning("Illegal input",
                               "Input is illegal. Enter a character in the range of (a-z) and (0-9)")
        e.delete(0, "end")
        return
    if e.get()[0:1] in chars_bank:
        messagebox.showwarning("Illegal input",
                               "Input was used before.")
        e.delete(0, "end")
        return
    else:
        len_align = (len(chars_bank) + 1) % 10
        if len_align == 0:
            chars_bank += "\n"
        chars_bank += e.get()[0:1]
        if e.get()[0:1].upper() in str(answer).upper():  # upper in order to ignore if the letter is written
            while e.get()[0:1].upper() in str(answer).upper():  # Check if its there more than once
                i = upper_word_list.index(e.get()[0:1].upper())  # Returns index of the letter guessed
                under_lines[i] = answer[i]
                answer[i] = " "
                upper_word_list[i] = " "
                counter -= 1
                if counter == 0:
                    messagebox.showinfo("WINNER", "You win!!!")
                    answer_ = messagebox.askyesno("HangMan", "Would you like to play again?")
                    if answer_ == 0:
                        quit_game()
                    else:
                        if os.path.isfile("temp.txt"):  # In case the file was created
                            os.remove("temp.txt")  # Delete file (no longer needed)
                        new_game_window.destroy()
                        play_window.destroy()
                        root.deiconify()
        else:
            guesses -= 1
            if guesses == 4:
                play_bg4 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("images/4guesses.jpg").resize((800, 450), Image.ANTIALIAS))
                canvas_play.background = play_bg4
                canvas_play.create_image(0, 0, anchor=NW, image=play_bg4)
            if guesses == 3:
                play_bg3 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("images/3guesses.jpg").resize((800, 450), Image.ANTIALIAS))
                canvas_play.background = play_bg3
                canvas_play.create_image(0, 0, anchor=NW, image=play_bg3)
            if guesses == 2:
                play_bg2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("images/2guesses.jpg").resize((800, 450), Image.ANTIALIAS))
                canvas_play.background = play_bg2
                canvas_play.create_image(0, 0, anchor=NW, image=play_bg2)
            if guesses == 1:
                play_bg1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("images/1guesses.jpg").resize((800, 450), Image.ANTIALIAS))
                canvas_play.background = play_bg1
                canvas_play.create_image(0, 0, anchor=NW, image=play_bg1)
            if guesses == 0:
                play_bg0 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("images/0guesses.jpg").resize((800, 450), Image.ANTIALIAS))
                canvas_play.background = play_bg0
                canvas_play.create_image(0, 0, anchor=NW, image=play_bg0)
                messagebox.showinfo("LOSER", "You lose!\nThe word was: " + wordd)
                answer_ = messagebox.askyesno("HangMan", "Would you like to play again?")
                if answer_ == 0:
                    quit_game()
                else:
                    if os.path.isfile("temp.txt"):  # In case the file was created
                        os.remove("temp.txt")  # Delete file (no longer needed)
                    new_game_window.destroy()
                    play_window.destroy()
                    root.deiconify()

    e.delete(0, "end")

    # letters_left_lbl = Label(play_window, text=str(counter) + " letters left to solve the word")
    # canvas_play.create_window(400, 370, anchor=CENTER, window=letters_left_lbl)
    #
    list_chars_bank = list(chars_bank)
    bank_lbl = Label(play_window, text="Used characters bank:\n" + " ".join(list_chars_bank).upper())
    canvas_play.create_window(70, 270, anchor=CENTER, window=bank_lbl)

    underlines_lbl = Label(play_window, text=" ".join(under_lines))
    canvas_play.create_window(400, 310, anchor=CENTER, window=underlines_lbl)

    guesses_lbl = Label(play_window, text="You have " + str(guesses) + " guesses left")
    canvas_play.create_window(400, 340, anchor=CENTER, window=guesses_lbl)


def play(hidden, word, count):
    new_game_window.withdraw()
    global play_bg
    global play_window
    global canvas_play

    global chars_bank
    global e

    global answer
    global upper_word_list
    global under_lines
    global wordd
    wordd = word

    global guesses
    guesses = 5

    global counter
    counter = count

    global list_chars_bank
    chars_bank = ""
    list_chars_bank = list(chars_bank)

    global word_change

    global letter_change

    play_window = Toplevel()
    play_window.title("HangMan")
    play_window.iconbitmap("images/icon.ico")
    play_window.geometry("800x400")
    play_window.resizable(width=False, height=False)
    play_window.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", disable_event)  # Disable window "X" (close) button

    # Create canvas and add background
    canvas_play = Canvas(play_window, width="800", height="450")
    canvas_play.pack()

    play_bg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("images/main_bg.jpg").resize((800, 450), Image.ANTIALIAS))
    canvas_play.background = play_bg
    canvas_play.create_image(0, 0, anchor=NW, image=play_bg)

    under_lines = list(hidden)  # Will make it easier to change chars in string
    answer = list(word)  # When done, do - "".join(list to join as string)
    upper_word = word.upper()
    upper_word_list = list(upper_word)
    chars_bank = ""

    # letters_left_lbl = Label(play_window, text=str(counter) + " letters left to solve the word")
    # canvas_play.create_window(400, 370, anchor=CENTER, window=letters_left_lbl)
    #
    underlines_lbl = Label(play_window, text=" ".join(under_lines))
    canvas_play.create_window(400, 310, anchor=CENTER, window=underlines_lbl)

    guesses_lbl = Label(play_window, text="You have " + str(guesses) + " guesses left")
    canvas_play.create_window(400, 340, anchor=CENTER, window=guesses_lbl)

    bank_lbl = Label(play_window, text="Used characters bank:\n" + " ".join(list_chars_bank).upper())
    canvas_play.create_window(70, 270, anchor=CENTER, window=bank_lbl)

    back_menu_btn_ = Button(play_window, text="Main Menu", borderwidth=5, width=15,
                            command=lambda: [main_menu_(),
                                             play_window.destroy(),
                                             new_game_window.destroy()])
    canvas_play.create_window(70, 370, anchor=CENTER, window=back_menu_btn_)

    e = Entry(play_window, width=4, borderwidth=2)
    canvas_play.create_window(380, 250, anchor=CENTER, window=e)

    assistance_btn = Button(play_window, text="Other options", width=15, borderwidth=5, command=assistance)
    canvas_play.create_window(70, 30, anchor=CENTER, window=assistance_btn)

    input_answer = Button(play_window, text="Confirm", command=my_answer, borderwidth=5)
    canvas_play.create_window(430, 250, anchor=CENTER, window=input_answer)

    music_btn = Button(play_window, text="Music", command=play_music)
    canvas_play.create_window(770, 380, anchor=CENTER, window=music_btn)


def score_board():
    return


def quit_game():
    if os.path.isfile("temp.txt"):  # In case the file was created
        os.remove("temp.txt")  # Delete file (no longer needed)
    root.destroy()


main_menu_()  # Start game
root.mainloop()
```

If needed, image are below:
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[link to the music file](https://voca.ro/1envbI4tIZ9K), [link to the ico image](http://www.iconj.com/ico/3/h/3hmz39fbe7.ico)

Comment: I have rolled back your latest edit. Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Answer (score 1):

### Code/Logic

```
    if not music_state:
        pygame.mixer.music.load("music/The Witcher 3 OST.mp3")
        pygame.mixer.music.play(loops=0)
        music_state = True
    else:
        pygame.mixer.music.stop()
        music_state = False
```

This is backwards. Since you're handling both cases, the natural thing to do would be

```
if music_state:
    pygame.mixer.music.stop()
    music_state = False
else:
    pygame.mixer.music.load("music/The Witcher 3 OST.mp3")
    pygame.mixer.music.play(loops=0)
    music_state = True
```

But also, you're flipping the `music_state` in both cases, so you can take that out and rather move it after the if-else and do

```
music_state = not music_state
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed the if statements of music_state as was answered.
Also, I've noticed that if the user lost the game and wishes to play again, the assistance options (letter change and word change) don't reset, so added:

```
word_change = 2
letter_change = 1
```

in the methods which handles losing.
Another issue is that when using option b (letter helper) the loop had issues on two occasions, if the answer contained more than one word then if the " " is chosen randomly as the letter helper, the loop will become infinite, and the second issue is if the word contained for example an upper and lower "A", then if the loop chooses "a", it won't handle the upper case "A".
Below is the new code:

```
import os
import random
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
from tkinter import messagebox
import pygame

# Window settings
root = Tk()
root.title("HangMan")
root.iconbitmap("images/icon.ico")
root.geometry("800x400")
root.resizable(width=False, height=False)


def disable_event():
    pass


root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", disable_event)  # Disable window "X" (close) button


pygame.mixer.init()
music_state = False


def play_music():
    global music_state

    if music_state:
        pygame.mixer.music.stop()
    else:
        pygame.mixer.music.load("music/The Witcher 3 OST.mp3")
        pygame.mixer.music.play(loops=0)
    music_state = not music_state


def main_menu_():
    root.deiconify()

    global main_menu_bg

    global letter_change
    letter_change = 1
    global word_change
    word_change = 2

    # Create canvas and add background
    canvas = Canvas(root, width="800", height="450")
    canvas.pack()

    main_menu_bg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("images/main_bg.jpg").resize((800, 450), Image.ANTIALIAS))
    canvas.background = main_menu_bg
    canvas.create_image(0, 0, anchor=NW, image=main_menu_bg)

    # Add buttons to canvas
    start_btn = Button(root, text="New Game", width=15, command=new_game, borderwidth=5)
    canvas.create_window(400, 150, anchor=CENTER, window=start_btn)

    score_btn = Button(root, text="Score Board", width=15, command=score_board, borderwidth=5)
    canvas.create_window(400, 210, anchor=CENTER, window=score_btn)

    quit_btn = Button(root, text="Quit", width=15, command=quit_game, borderwidth=5)
    canvas.create_window(400, 270, anchor=CENTER, window=quit_btn)

    music_btn = Button(root, text="Music", command=play_music)
    canvas.create_window(770, 380, anchor=CENTER, window=music_btn)


def new_game():
    root.withdraw()  # Hide root window, to make it visible again use root.deiconify()

    global new_game_bg
    global new_game_window

    new_game_window = Toplevel()
    new_game_window.title("HangMan")
    new_game_window.iconbitmap("images/icon.ico")
    new_game_window.geometry("800x400")
    new_game_window.resizable(width=False, height=False)
    new_game_window.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", disable_event)  # Disable window "X" (close) button

    # Create canvas and add background
    canvas_new_game = Canvas(new_game_window, width="800", height="450")
    canvas_new_game.pack()

    new_game_bg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("images/main_bg.jpg").resize((800, 450), Image.ANTIALIAS))
    canvas_new_game.background = new_game_bg
    canvas_new_game.create_image(0, 0, anchor=NW, image=new_game_bg)

    instructions_lbl = Label(new_game_window, text="There are 4 different categories.\n"
                                                   "Choose as many as you'd like,"
                                                   "\nbut do choose wisely, this is not going to be easy!",
                             bg="#a5a0b6")
    canvas_new_game.create_window(400, 60, anchor=CENTER, window=instructions_lbl)

    # Will help knowing which categories were chosen
    var1 = StringVar(value="")
    var2 = StringVar(value="")
    var3 = StringVar(value="")
    var4 = StringVar(value="")

    anime_btn = Checkbutton(new_game_window, text="Anime", variable=var1, onvalue="a", offvalue="")
    canvas_new_game.create_window(340, 120, anchor=CENTER, window=anime_btn)
    games_btn = Checkbutton(new_game_window, text="Games", variable=var2, onvalue="g", offvalue="")
    canvas_new_game.create_window(440, 120, anchor=CENTER, window=games_btn)
    movies_btn = Checkbutton(new_game_window, text="Movies", variable=var3, onvalue="m", offvalue="")
    canvas_new_game.create_window(340, 170, anchor=CENTER, window=movies_btn)
    tv_btn = Checkbutton(new_game_window, text="TV-Shows", variable=var4, onvalue="t", offvalue="")
    canvas_new_game.create_window(440, 170, anchor=CENTER, window=tv_btn)

    start_new_game_btn = Button(new_game_window, text="Start new game", width=15,
                                command=lambda: [prepare(var1.get() + var2.get() + var3.get() + var4.get())]
                                , borderwidth=5)
    canvas_new_game.create_window(390, 220, anchor=CENTER, window=start_new_game_btn)

    back_menu_btn = Button(new_game_window, text="Main Menu", width=15, command=lambda: [main_menu_(),
                                                                                         new_game_window.destroy()]
                           , borderwidth=5)
    canvas_new_game.create_window(390, 260, anchor=CENTER, window=back_menu_btn)

    # quit_game_btn = Button(new_game_window, text="Quit game", width=15, command=quit_game)
    # canvas_new_game.create_window(390, 300, anchor=CENTER, window=quit_game_btn)

    music_btn = Button(new_game_window, text="Music", command=play_music)
    canvas_new_game.create_window(770, 380, anchor=CENTER, window=music_btn)


# choice variable will contain the user's wanted category for the game
def prepare(choice):
    global count_lines

    # Create file of words
    movies = open("movies list.txt", "r")  # Open word files
    games = open("games list.txt", "r")
    tv = open("tv list.txt", "r")
    anime = open("anime list.txt", "r")
    categories = ""
    file = open("temp.txt", "a+")  # File which will contain words from chosen categories
    if "a" or "g" or "m" or "t" in choice:
        if "m" in choice:
            categories += "Movies / "
            for i in movies.readlines():
                file.write(i)
        if "g" in choice:
            categories += "Games / "
            for j in games.readlines():
                file.write(j)
        if "t" in choice:
            categories += "TV-Shows / "
            for k in tv.readlines():
                file.write(k)
        if "a" in choice:
            categories += "Anime / "
            for t in anime.readlines():
                file.write(t)
        categories = categories[0:-3]  # Will go in label
    movies.close()  # Close word files
    anime.close()
    tv.close()
    games.close()
    file.close()

    # Get lines count
    categories_file = open("temp.txt", "r")
    count_lines = get_lines_count(categories_file)
    categories_file.close()

    # Get random word to guess
    random_num = random.randint(1, count_lines)  # Get a random integer
    word_to_guess = get_word(random_num)
    word_to_guess = word_to_guess[0:-1]  # Remove the "\n" char

    # Count word chars
    chars_count = get_chars_count(list(word_to_guess))

    # Create a variable same length as word to guess but made from _
    under_lines_guess = hide_word(word_to_guess)

    play(under_lines_guess, word_to_guess, chars_count)


def hide_word(word):
    hidden = ""
    for hide in range(len(word)):  # for 0 in (x-1)
        if word[hide] == " ":
            hidden += " "
        else:
            hidden += "_"
    return hidden


def get_chars_count(count_chars):
    counter_chars = 0
    for index in count_chars:
        if index != " ":
            counter_chars += 1
    return counter_chars


def get_lines_count(file):
    return sum(1 for line in file)  # For each line count 1+1+...


def get_word(random_number):
    global count_lines

    f = open("temp.txt", "r")
    lines = f.readlines()
    ret = lines[random_number - 1]
    f.close()
    f_new = open("temp.txt", "w")
    for line in lines:  # Write all lines to the file except the one with the word used
        if line != lines[random_number - 1]:
            f_new.write(line)
    f_new.close()

    count_lines -= 1  # Since one line is gone (used and deleted)

    return ret


def close_window():
    option_window.destroy()


def option_a():
    global count_lines
    global word_change
    global letter_change

    if word_change <= 0:
        messagebox.showwarning("Used it all", "You used all of your word change options!")
        option_window.destroy()
        return

    # Get random word to guess
    random_num = random.randint(1, count_lines)  # Get a random integer
    word_to_guess = get_word(random_num)
    word_to_guess = word_to_guess[0:-1]  # Remove the "\n" char

    # Count word chars
    chars_count = get_chars_count(list(word_to_guess))

    # Create a variable same length as word to guess but made from _
    under_lines_guess = hide_word(word_to_guess)
    word_change -= 1

    play_window.destroy()
    option_window.destroy()

    play(under_lines_guess, word_to_guess, chars_count)


def option_b():
    global chars_bank
    global counter
    global letter_change
    global word_change

    if letter_change <= 0:
        messagebox.showwarning("Used it all", "You used all of your letter helper options!")
        option_window.destroy()
        return

    answer_b = list(wordd)  # When done, do - "".join(list to join as string)
    upper_word = wordd.upper()
    upper_word_list_b = list(upper_word)

    len_wordd = len(wordd) - 1
    used_check = True

    while used_check:
        random_num = random.randint(0, len_wordd)
        char_reveal = wordd[random_num]

        if char_reveal.upper() not in str(chars_bank).upper() and char_reveal not in " ":
            chars_bank += char_reveal
            while char_reveal.upper() in str(answer_b).upper():
                # print(char_reveal.upper() + str(answer_b).upper())
                i = upper_word_list_b.index(char_reveal.upper())  # Change input char and it's duplicates
                under_lines[i] = answer_b[i]
                answer_b[i] = " "
                upper_word_list_b[i] = " "
                counter -= 1
            if counter == 0:
                messagebox.showinfo("WINNER", "You win!!!")
                answer_ = messagebox.askyesno("HangMan", "Would you like to play again?")
                if answer_ == 0:
                    quit_game()
                else:
                    letter_change = 1  # Initialize after user loses
                    word_change = 2

                    if os.path.isfile("temp.txt"):  # In case the file was created
                        os.remove("temp.txt")  # Delete file (no longer needed)
                    new_game_window.destroy()
                    play_window.destroy()
                    option_window.destroy()
                    root.deiconify()
            used_check = False

    letter_change -= 1

    list_chars_bank_ = list(chars_bank)
    bank_lbl = Label(play_window, text="Used characters bank:\n" + " ".join(list_chars_bank_).upper())
    canvas_play.create_window(70, 270, anchor=CENTER, window=bank_lbl)

    underlines_lbl = Label(play_window, text=" ".join(under_lines))
    canvas_play.create_window(400, 310, anchor=CENTER, window=underlines_lbl)

    guesses_lbl = Label(play_window, text="You have " + str(guesses) + " guesses left")
    canvas_play.create_window(400, 340, anchor=CENTER, window=guesses_lbl)

    option_window.destroy()


def assistance():
    global word_change
    global letter_change

    global option_window

    if word_change == 0 and letter_change == 0:
        messagebox.showinfo("Assistance menu", "You don't have any more assistance options to use.")
    else:
        option_window = Toplevel()
        option_window.title("Assistance menu")
        option_window.iconbitmap("images/icon.ico")
        option_window.geometry("270x219")
        option_window.resizable(width=False, height=False)
        option_window.attributes("-topmost", "true")

        # Create canvas and add background
        canvas_option = Canvas(option_window, width="270", height="219")
        canvas_option.pack()

        option_bg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("images/choosewisely.jpg").resize((270, 219), Image.ANTIALIAS))
        canvas_option.background = option_bg
        canvas_option.create_image(0, 0, anchor=NW, image=option_bg)

        option_text = ("Choose an option:\nA) Change word (uses left: " + str(word_change)
                       + ")\nB) Letter helper (uses left: " + str(letter_change) + ")")

        option_lbl = Label(option_window, text=option_text)
        canvas_option.create_window(135, 55, anchor=CENTER, window=option_lbl)

        option_a_btn = Button(option_window, text="Option A", borderwidth=5, command=option_a)
        canvas_option.create_window(85, 150, anchor=CENTER, window=option_a_btn)

        option_b_btn = Button(option_window, text="Option B", borderwidth=5, command=option_b)
        canvas_option.create_window(185, 150, anchor=CENTER, window=option_b_btn)

        cancel_btn = Button(option_window, text="Nah... I don't need any help", borderwidth=5,
                            command=close_window)
        canvas_option.create_window(135, 195, anchor=CENTER, window=cancel_btn)


def my_answer():
    global chars_bank

    global wordd

    global counter

    global guesses

    global list_chars_bank

    global under_lines

    global word_change
    global letter_change

    if e.get()[0:1] in "\n =+-*/.`~!@#$%^&*()_,';:":
        messagebox.showwarning("Illegal input",
                               "Input is illegal. Enter a character in the range of (a-z) and (0-9)")
        e.delete(0, "end")
        return
    if e.get()[0:1] in chars_bank:
        messagebox.showwarning("Illegal input",
                               "Input was used before.")
        e.delete(0, "end")
        return
    else:
        len_align = (len(chars_bank) + 1) % 10
        if len_align == 0:
            chars_bank += "\n"
        chars_bank += e.get()[0:1]
        if e.get()[0:1].upper() in str(answer).upper():  # upper in order to ignore if the letter is written
            while e.get()[0:1].upper() in str(answer).upper():  # Check if its there more than once
                i = upper_word_list.index(e.get()[0:1].upper())  # Returns index of the letter guessed
                under_lines[i] = answer[i]
                answer[i] = " "
                upper_word_list[i] = " "
                counter -= 1
                if counter == 0:
                    messagebox.showinfo("WINNER", "You win!!!")
                    answer_ = messagebox.askyesno("HangMan", "Would you like to play again?")
                    if answer_ == 0:
                        quit_game()
                    else:
                        if os.path.isfile("temp.txt"):  # In case the file was created
                            os.remove("temp.txt")  # Delete file (no longer needed)
                        new_game_window.destroy()
                        play_window.destroy()
                        root.deiconify()
        else:
            guesses -= 1
            if guesses == 4:
                play_bg4 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("images/4guesses.jpg").resize((800, 450), Image.ANTIALIAS))
                canvas_play.background = play_bg4
                canvas_play.create_image(0, 0, anchor=NW, image=play_bg4)
            if guesses == 3:
                play_bg3 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("images/3guesses.jpg").resize((800, 450), Image.ANTIALIAS))
                canvas_play.background = play_bg3
                canvas_play.create_image(0, 0, anchor=NW, image=play_bg3)
            if guesses == 2:
                play_bg2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("images/2guesses.jpg").resize((800, 450), Image.ANTIALIAS))
                canvas_play.background = play_bg2
                canvas_play.create_image(0, 0, anchor=NW, image=play_bg2)
            if guesses == 1:
                play_bg1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("images/1guesses.jpg").resize((800, 450), Image.ANTIALIAS))
                canvas_play.background = play_bg1
                canvas_play.create_image(0, 0, anchor=NW, image=play_bg1)
            if guesses == 0:
                play_bg0 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("images/0guesses.jpg").resize((800, 450), Image.ANTIALIAS))
                canvas_play.background = play_bg0
                canvas_play.create_image(0, 0, anchor=NW, image=play_bg0)
                messagebox.showinfo("LOSER", "You lose!\nThe word was: " + wordd)
                answer_ = messagebox.askyesno("HangMan", "Would you like to play again?")
                if answer_ == 0:
                    quit_game()
                else:
                    word_change = 2
                    letter_change = 1
                    if os.path.isfile("temp.txt"):  # In case the file was created
                        os.remove("temp.txt")  # Delete file (no longer needed)
                    new_game_window.destroy()
                    play_window.destroy()
                    root.deiconify()

    e.delete(0, "end")

    # letters_left_lbl = Label(play_window, text=str(counter) + " letters left to solve the word")
    # canvas_play.create_window(400, 370, anchor=CENTER, window=letters_left_lbl)
    #
    list_chars_bank = list(chars_bank)
    bank_lbl = Label(play_window, text="Used characters bank:\n" + " ".join(list_chars_bank).upper())
    canvas_play.create_window(70, 270, anchor=CENTER, window=bank_lbl)

    underlines_lbl = Label(play_window, text=" ".join(under_lines))
    canvas_play.create_window(400, 310, anchor=CENTER, window=underlines_lbl)

    guesses_lbl = Label(play_window, text="You have " + str(guesses) + " guesses left")
    canvas_play.create_window(400, 340, anchor=CENTER, window=guesses_lbl)


def play(hidden, word, count):
    new_game_window.withdraw()
    global play_bg
    global play_window
    global canvas_play

    global chars_bank
    global e

    global answer
    global upper_word_list
    global under_lines
    global wordd
    wordd = word

    global guesses
    guesses = 5

    global counter
    counter = count

    global list_chars_bank
    chars_bank = ""
    list_chars_bank = list(chars_bank)

    global word_change

    global letter_change

    play_window = Toplevel()
    play_window.title("HangMan")
    play_window.iconbitmap("images/icon.ico")
    play_window.geometry("800x400")
    play_window.resizable(width=False, height=False)
    play_window.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", disable_event)  # Disable window "X" (close) button

    # Create canvas and add background
    canvas_play = Canvas(play_window, width="800", height="450")
    canvas_play.pack()

    play_bg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("images/main_bg.jpg").resize((800, 450), Image.ANTIALIAS))
    canvas_play.background = play_bg
    canvas_play.create_image(0, 0, anchor=NW, image=play_bg)

    under_lines = list(hidden)  # Will make it easier to change chars in string
    answer = list(word)  # When done, do - "".join(list to join as string)
    upper_word = word.upper()
    upper_word_list = list(upper_word)
    chars_bank = ""

    # letters_left_lbl = Label(play_window, text=str(counter) + " letters left to solve the word")
    # canvas_play.create_window(400, 370, anchor=CENTER, window=letters_left_lbl)
    #
    underlines_lbl = Label(play_window, text=" ".join(under_lines))
    canvas_play.create_window(400, 310, anchor=CENTER, window=underlines_lbl)

    guesses_lbl = Label(play_window, text="You have " + str(guesses) + " guesses left")
    canvas_play.create_window(400, 340, anchor=CENTER, window=guesses_lbl)

    bank_lbl = Label(play_window, text="Used characters bank:\n" + " ".join(list_chars_bank).upper())
    canvas_play.create_window(70, 270, anchor=CENTER, window=bank_lbl)

    back_menu_btn_ = Button(play_window, text="Main Menu", borderwidth=5, width=15,
                            command=lambda: [main_menu_(),
                                             play_window.destroy(),
                                             new_game_window.destroy()])
    canvas_play.create_window(70, 370, anchor=CENTER, window=back_menu_btn_)

    e = Entry(play_window, width=4, borderwidth=2)
    canvas_play.create_window(380, 250, anchor=CENTER, window=e)

    assistance_btn = Button(play_window, text="Other options", width=15, borderwidth=5, command=assistance)
    canvas_play.create_window(70, 30, anchor=CENTER, window=assistance_btn)

    input_answer = Button(play_window, text="Confirm", command=my_answer, borderwidth=5)
    canvas_play.create_window(430, 250, anchor=CENTER, window=input_answer)

    music_btn = Button(play_window, text="Music", command=play_music)
    canvas_play.create_window(770, 380, anchor=CENTER, window=music_btn)


def score_board():
    return


def quit_game():
    if os.path.isfile("temp.txt"):  # In case the file was created
        os.remove("temp.txt")  # Delete file (no longer needed)
    root.destroy()


main_menu_()  # Start game
root.mainloop()
```